# PostgreSQL 8.3 data types: xml vs varchar

Tags: xml, postgresql, database-design

There's xml data type in Postgres, I never used it before so I'd like to hear opinions. Downsides and upsides vs using regular varchar (or Text) column to store xml.

The text I'm going to store is xml, well-formed, UTF-8. No need to search by it ([I've read](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/datatype-xml.html) searching by xml is slow).

This XML actually is data prepared for PDF generation with Apache FOP. XML *can* be generated dynamically from data found elsewhere (other Postgres tables), it's stored as is only so that I won't need to generate it *twice*. Kinda backup#2 for already generated PDF documents.

Anything else to know? Good practices, performance, maintenance, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XML` differs from `TEXT` only logically: first, the input is checked for validity, second, the `XML` type lack comparison operators so you cannot index it, compare, use in `UNION` or `DISTINCT` etc.

If you are not going to search against it using indexes and want to make an extra check for validity, then use `XML` safely.

Comment: Note that you can work around the lack of comparison operators by casting to `text`, e.g. `create unique index foo on bar(cast(xmlcol as text))`.

Comment: `@Alex Brasetvik`: … or just store the column as `TEXT` and convert it to `XML` for `XML`-related purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't compared performance, but a good thing with using the XML-type is that you'll get the server to ensure the XML is well-formed. Perhaps later on you'll have use for any of the many [XML-functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-xml.html) available.